# Image bank folder with Plone on multilingual site, browseable from TinyMCE 1.3

Tags: tinymce, plone, linguaplone

I'd like to create an image bank folder in Plone

- All photos are uploaded here by default (even from TinyMCE)
- All photos are language neutral by default: can be set per type with LinguaPlone somehow? To be shared across languages.
- Album view (easy)
- The folder is in site root below /en, /de etc. language folders and browseable from TinyMCE (the latest beta)

What suggestion and experience you have from the set-up described above? The goal is to have fool-proof setup that

- The site users always upload photos to the same folder
- The site users always start browser "Add image" from the the same folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to do the follow up.

This problem has been now solved:

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/08/03/adding-custom-shortcut-links-to-tinymce-dialogs-in-plone/

Answer (score 0):

To not fight against the framework I would try a synchronization between photos repositories of each languages.

/en/photos
/fr/photos
/xx/photos

If photos are uploaded under one of them, copy it to others as the translation of the created one.

It will be easier than playing outside of navigationroot, tinymce, ...